# How do I find out the hostname of my Mac OS X server?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I'm trying to connect with `mysql_connect` using PHP.

I was wondering how to find the hostname when I turn my MacBook into a server by turning on the personal webpage.

I have Apache, MySQL and PHP enabled.

Is the hostname what you `ssh` into? It says that my computer's name is `spiderman` and it could be accessed with `spiderman.local`, but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using my IP address.

Comment: Are you SSHing into the computer from the same local network?

Answer (score 30):

In a terminal run the command:

```
$ hostname
```

The environment variable `$HOSTNAME` may not necessarily be set.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you get the hostname by typing

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

in Terminal.

But for your server setup, if no one has messed with configuration, localhost will be the hostname to use; in safe mode, localhost:3306 (that is port 3306) is the default. 
(cf. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php )

BUT: You should make sure that you actually started the MySQL server. Starting command depends on your installation.

Comment: This environment variable frequently won't be set...

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you are doing it from within a script program where the environment has been set up correctly, either the following may work or suit you:

```
~$ uname -n
roberts.e.co.za
~$ echo $HOSTNAME
roberts.e.co.za
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect to MySQL running locally, try 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

### System Preferences.app > Sharing > Computer Name

[image: Sharing Preferences]